# Access denied for user 'root'@'%'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

When executing this query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\oto@increase.dk\Documents\Unity\Marketo files\mkto_export_split_af.csv'
INTO TABLE DB_M3_Medium.Unity_Marketo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@dummy, C_EMAILADDRESS, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, 
@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, C_WANT_GENERAL_NEWSLETTER1, C_WANT_ASSETSTORE_NEWS1, C_WANT_ASSET24HOUR_DEALS1, @dummy, @dummy, C_WANT_PROMOTIONAL_OFFERS1, C_WANT_SIMWIZ_NEWS1, C_WANT_UT_CLOUD_NEWS1, C_WANT_UT_GAMES_NEWS1, @dummy, 
@dummy, C_WANT_ASSETSTORE_MADNESS_NEWS, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy);
```

I get an error:

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)   0.047 sec
```

However, I wouldn't expect that because I did some search and most suggestions refer to granting a full access to the root user and I did that.

I have executed: `GRANT ALL ON '%'.* TO root@'%';'` on my `mysql` server and the response I've gotten was: `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

Besides that, I find it strange, that the `LOAD DATA INFILE` error shows up so quickly (in 0.047 sec), which looks like it never even got past `Workbench` to request the server.

I am using a `MySQL 5.6` and the DB is hosted on `RDS`.

Comment: I had the same trouble with databases hosted on RDS, but when I tried on a server running MySQL in EC2 it worked...

Why not insert the csv with an ETL tool? I recommend Pentaho